# How do I specify the "path" section of a HTTP Post using Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, httpclient

For example, this example is given on http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039 :

```
POST /foo.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; <blah, blah>
<other blah goes here>
```

I'm using Apache's HttpClient ( v.3.4.5 ), and I want to be able to specify the 'path' shown above, the '/foo.php' section.  How do I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your problem, but usually you would specify that together with the URL, when creating the `HttpPost`: `new HttpPost("http://host.com/foo.php")`

Comment: In my testing, if I include that, I get an error 404.  If I don't include it, I get an error 302 ( and I have not yet dealt with redirects ).  My interpretation of this is that I get an error if I append, and no error if I don't, implying that appending it is wrong.  Is my interpretation incorrect?

Comment: @qqilihq - Ok, looking at [Problem simulating HTTP POST using HttpClient]"(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582471/problem-simulating-http-post-using-httpclient?rq=1), you are correct ( or, more correctly, I am wrong. ) Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @qqilihq - Make your comment an answer and I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the whole URL with hostname and path in your `HttpPost`:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpPost("http://host.com/foo.php");
```