# How do I extract login-protected data from a website using Java?

Tags: java, htmlunit, apache-commons-httpclient, screen-scraping

I've been using Java to extract some values from one website. However, I now need to extract some values from another website, but this website requires you to login to see the page. I have a username and password that I can use to login, but I have been unsuccessful with using an automated login on Java using HTTPclient or HTMLUnit.

Is there any way I would be able to get round this and extract the data from the login protected page?

Comment: JSoup is pretty good with that type of stuff. I would see what their library has to offer.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to do it without making the program find the form, fill in the form, press enter etc

Comment: No you will still need to authenticate yourself, but JSoup may have some kind of module in place that may make authentication of logins easier

Comment: Could you give me any links to help me?

Comment: Try looking at their API to see if there is anything of use there. I havent used their library in a year so im not sure what they have: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/

Answer (score 3):

1. In your code, simulate a user login.  Typically that means POSTING to the login URL with username and password values in the appropriate form parameters.  To see what this looks like from an HTTP perspective, use a tools that shows you the contents of the request (wireshark, browser plugins).
2. Capture the cookies that are returned from the POST of the login page.  Likely one or more of these are session cookies - i.e. cookies that identify your session with the server.
3. Include those cookies in subsequent requests to that site.  The requests should not be recognized as having come from an authenticated user.

Comment: As i said in the question, I have tried this and been unsuccessful. Is there a way to do it without doing this, or if not, could you provide me with a template of code that I can input the appropriate values for the website I want to log into? Especially the cookies part, I'm having trouble with that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582471/problem-simulating-http-post-using-httpclient the answer that has `HTTPContext` might be what you're looking for.